# Hibernate Lazy loading not working with Spring Boot => failed to lazily initialize a collection of role could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, lazy-loading

I am trying to implement **Lazy loading** for our **Fund** entity that has **one-to-many** relationship with **FundAlternateId** entity by using **FetchType.Lazy**

When I try to access the fund endpoint, I get the following error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily
> initialize a collection of role:
> com.example.model.Fund.fundAlternateIds, could not initialize proxy -
> no Session
>
> JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of
> role: com.example.model.model.Fund.fundAlternateIds, could not
> initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain:
> java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->
> com.example.model.model.Fund["fundAlternateIds"]) ;    at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:397)
> ;

Here are my project files:

**Fund Entity**

```
@Entity(name="fund")
@Table(name="mv_fund_info")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Fund implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "fund_port_id")
    private String fundPortId;


    @Column(name = "fund_full_name")
    private String fundFullName;

    @Column(name = "fund_short_name")
    private String fundShortName;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "associatedFund",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<FundAlternateId> fundAlternateIds;
}
```

**FundAlternateId Class**

```
@Entity(name="fundAlternateId")
@Table(name="mv_fund_alternate_id")
@Getter
@Setter
public class FundAlternateId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="alternate_id_ins_id")
    private Long alternateIdInsId;

    @Column(name="alternate_id_value")
    @Text
    private String alternateIdValue;

    @Column(name="alternate_id_type")
    @Text
    private String alternateIdType;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="fund_port_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Fund associatedFund;
}
```

**Rest Controller**

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response getPublicFundAttributes() {
  List<Fund> publicFunds = fundService.getAllPublicFunds(offset,limit, sortBy);
  return Response.status(Status.OK).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(publicFunds).build();
}
```

**FundService**

```
@Service
@Transactional("myTransactionManager")
public class FundServiceImpl implements FundService {

    @Autowired
    FundDao fundDao;

    @Override
    public List<Fund> getAllPublicFunds(Integer pageNo, Integer pageSize, String sortBy) {
        List<Fund> fundList = fundDao.getAllPublicFunds(pageNo, pageSize, sortBy);
        return fundList;
    }
}
```

**FundDao**

@Named("fundDao")
public class FundDaoImpl implements FundDao {

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("fundRepository")
FundRepository fundRepository;

@Override
public List<Fund> getAllPublicFunds() {
    List<Fund> pagedResult = fundRepository.findAll();
    return pagedResult;
}
```

}

**FundRepository**

```
@Repository("fundRepository")
public interface FundRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Fund, String> {}
```

**Configuration Class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.example.repository"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "myEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "myTransactionManager"
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationDatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "myEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("postGresDataSource") HikariDataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.example.model"});
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(buildJpaPropertyMap());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
        adapter.setShowSql(false);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);

        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "postGresDataSource")
    public HikariDataSource getDataSource() {
        HikariDataSource dataSource  = new HikariDataSource();

        try {
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("ApplicationDatabaseConfiguration.getDataSource() has issue to get data source:", e);
        }

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(userId);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setAutoCommit(true);
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(25);
        dataSource.setMaxLifetime(300000);
        dataSource.setIdleTimeout(30000);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "sleeveTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(getEntityManagerFactory(getDataSource()).getObject());
        tm.setDataSource(getDataSource());

        return tm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Once your transaction is committed the `List<Fund>` you are having in controller is list of detached `Fund` objects which has this relationship. Now when jackson is trying to serialize the List, it needs the children `List<FundAlternateId>` as well, but since it is an entity object with fetch strategy set as lazy, it will try to fetch initialize the `List<FundAlternateId>`, but it will fail to do so, because object is not attached to persistence context. You need to build your response inside a the transaction only or you could write projections (DTOs) from custom query,

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @code_mechanic in comments, there are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Initialize all the lazy references in `Transaction` (your service layer)
2. Set all the lazy references to null in `Controller` before returning the API response.

I have developed two utility methods, which you can use to dynamically check whether the lazy object was initialized or not. You can use these methods in controller layer:

```
/**
 * Was collection initialized.
 *
 * @param c the c
 * @return true, if successful
 */
public static boolean wasCollectionInitialized(Object c) {
    if (!(c instanceof PersistentCollection)) {
        return true;
    }

    PersistentCollection pc = (PersistentCollection) c;
    return pc.wasInitialized();
}

/**
 * Was object initialized.
 *
 * @param c the c
 * @return true, if successful
 */
public static boolean wasObjectInitialized(Object c) {
    if (!(c instanceof HibernateProxy)) {
        return true;
    }

    HibernateProxy pc = (HibernateProxy) c;
    return !pc.getHibernateLazyInitializer().isUninitialized();
}
```